# AppleScript to fast forward YouTube videos

Tags: applescript, video, google-chrome, youtube

I'm trying to use AppleScript to fast forward YouTube videos by 10 seconds in Chrome, but the following code doesn't work; I get *missing value* as output, instead. What I am doing wrong?

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows
        tell t
            if URL starts with "http://www.youtube.com/watch" or URL starts with "https://www.youtube.com/watch" then
                execute javascript "
            var player = document.querySelector('video');
            player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition() + 10000);
            "
                exit repeat
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.